# Change volume in only one of the audio channels with FFMPEG

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I need, in an android application using FFmpeg, to separately adjust the volume of an mp3 file setting two different values for the two channels. 
This is the command I'm executing:

```
[-i, 0.mp3, -filter_complex, channelsplit[lpre][rpre];[lpre]volume=0.0[l];
[rpre]volume=1.0[r];[l][r]amix=inputs=2, 0.wav]
```

In this case for example I'd expect the output to have a mute left channel and the right channel as normal. The result is instead a wave with the same volume on both channels.

Comment: Use amerge instead of amix.

Comment: I substituted amix with amerge and this time it failed with these messages:     [Parsed_amerge_3 @ 0xb5c204b0] No channel layout for input 1
Last message repeated 1 times
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xb5c09040] The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_3
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
Error configuring complex filters.
I/O error

Comment: Add `pan=1c` before the volume filters.

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly, please?

Comment: e,g, `[lpre]pan=1c,volume=0.0[l]`

Comment: thanks, I tried but got the same error message of above (No channel layout for input 1...etc)

Comment: I also tried to add the pan command to the amix (instead of amerge) and there were no errors but the output is a complete mute audio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a direct method to alter the volumes of channels:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af "pan=stereo:c0=0*c0|c1=1*c1" out.wav
```

Since you're on a linux-based OS, you may have to replace the double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: I'll try right now. In the meanwhile, how would this code behave in case the input is not stereo?

Comment: It'll downmix to stereo. But with pan, you can output to any supported channel layout supported by ffmpeg. See the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan-1) for pan.

Comment: My input can be mono. I tried the command and the result is again an output having same volume on both sides. I'd expect to have my left (or right) volume higher/lower than the other...but both sides have same volume.

Comment: It doesn't seem I'm too lucky....Failed to open report "ffmpeg-20170413-120908.log": Read-only file system. I can post you anyway the log of ffmpeg in onSuccess which is probably good enough

Comment: I posted the log as an aswer. BTW, thanks for your help so far, thumb up

Answer (score 0):

```
04-13 12:19:41.251: I/mp3 to wav(25097): [-i, /storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/volumi/0.mp3, -af, pan=stereo|c0=0*c0|c1=1*c1, /storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/volumi/0.wav]
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097): successffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097): [mp3 @ 0xb5bd7000] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 417.
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097): Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/volumi/0.mp3':
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   Duration: 00:00:00.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 139 kb/s
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097): [Parsed_pan_0 @ 0xb5bdd410] Pure channel mapping detected: M 1
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097): Output #0, wav, to '/storage/emulated/0/beatmachine/volumi/0.wav':
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   Metadata:
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):     ISFT            : Lavf57.25.100
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):     Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):     Metadata:
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 pcm_s16le
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097): Stream mapping:
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097):   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097): Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097): size=      50kB time=00:00:00.28 bitrate=1413.4kbits/s speed=31.7x    
04-13 12:19:41.574: I/ffmpeg(25097): video:0kB audio:50kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.153883%
```

Comment: Log shows command executed as expected. Check playback on another device, preferably a PC/Mac where the player allows you to pan.

Comment: and you are right, I tried with VLC player and I could recognise the pan, thank you!